# In a series of item each with negative margin, how to make each item appear below the previous item?

Tags: css

As per project design, I need to display a series of item, each one partially on top of the next one.

Using negative margin I could accomplish that:

[image]

The only issue is: each new item is *above* the previous one, whereas I want to achieve the opposite.

How?

Notes: the number of items is unknown (they come from an API). The order of the items is important.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Draikin1/pen/bZLjxM)

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: yellow;
    margin-right: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried a `z-index`? That's the easiest way.

Comment: Number of items is unknown (comes from API)

Comment: What's the actual design? Are they circles like in the example above? In short you fake it by hiding the overflow and adding the "edge" of the next circle as `pseudo class` in the previous element.

Comment: not possible with CSS I'll have to say without changing order and with unknown number of items... use JS - `$($('.container .item').get().reverse()).each(function(index) {
  $(this).css("z-index", index);
})` and add `position: relative` to `item`

Comment: @kukkuz It's completely possible without JS. You just have to be willing to use some smoke and mirrors to get the correct appearance. And you don't have z-index limitations.

Comment: Simple, effective, and dynamic JS solution posted below.

Answer (score 1):

If you can reverse the order of items you can do something like this:

**Flexbox**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

If you do not need the flexbox you can do something like this:

**Table**

```css
.container {
  display: table;
}

.item {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the z-index property, using larger numbers to the ones on top.

```
.item1 {
    z-index: 3;
}
.item2 {
    z-index: 2;
}
.item3 {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Since the number of items is not known in advance, assign to the style property on each element directly.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to specify that the number of items is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but you can do some flex magic by flipping and reversing them. All you need to do is change your container css to the following.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: -8px;
  order:-1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but order is important, so nope

Comment: @drake035 if youre getting them from an api you could just prepend instead of append to the container

Answer (score 0):

**Fully CSS, Respects order of elements, NO JS or Z-index gymnastics**

I haven't seen the actual design so not sure if it will work this way. But since order is important (not just decoration) here's one way to do it.

Unfortunately, this **solution DOES require adding an additional element and Knowing sizes** (you wouldn't need sizes if it were a vertical overlap and full width for example)

Basically, we're using smoke and mirrors... The idea is to put everything in a container with `overflow: hidden` and then add another element over the top, positioned so the overflow hides it. :-)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
  padding: 0;
}
.item span {
  display:block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;


  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.item:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -42px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: aqua;
  z-index: 10;
}
.item:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}
.item:first-child:before {
  display:none;
}

.example2 .item:before{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><span>A</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>B</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>C</span></div>
</div>

<div class="container example2">
  <div class="item"><span>A</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>B</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>C</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>D</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>E</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>F</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>G</span></div>
</div>
```

Math is a bit off in this case since the 1px border adds 2px to the total width...

Answer (score 0):

A little JS to the rescue... Add `position: relative;` to the `.item` class, and this should work:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

if (items) {
  let z = items.length;

  items.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.zIndex = z;
    z--;
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```